# Override Default Pawn's position and orientation in Unreal makes the Oculus IPD to 0

Tags: unreal-engine4, stereo-3d, oculus

We are doing a VR experiment using Oculus and Unreal. In this experiment, we just use Oculus as a display device and disable Oculus's positioning and orientation like the following:

[image]

And we use the Vicon to provide the positioning and the orientation for the default pawn, the blueprint looks like the following:

[image]

After doing this, we realize that the ipd of oculus is set to a very small number (close to 0).  We search solution for days on the internet but found nothing. Does anyone one knows how to solve this?

Thanks,

Mando

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found what cause this issue. After I disable the tracking ability of Oculus in Unreal, it loses the control of the virtual camera of the default pawn. The way I solved this is to enable the oculus tracking but override its position parameters and orientation parameters in each frame. Then, I set the world to meter(w2m) to match the virtual world's unit and change the IPD accordingly in the console. I will keep digging more information and edit this answer with more details later.